# Why doesn't fun(int *p) alter the value of the pointer?

Tags: c, pointers

```
void fun(int *p) 
{ 
  int q = 10; 
  p = &q; 
}     

int main() 
{ 
  int r = 20; 
  int *p = &r; 
  fun(p); 
  printf("%d", *p); 
  return 0; 
}
```

I have an understanding of pointers, however it was my guess that `printf` should display 10, although the website's compiler and other compiler say the value remains 20.

Can anyone explain why?

Does fun() have an affect on the pointer `p`? Why or why not?

Comment: `p` is *local*.

Comment: `fun(int *p)` _does_ alter the pointer value with `p = &q;`.  Yet `p` in `fun()` is not the `p` in `main()`.

Comment: 8 answers for this question? Really?

Comment: Thanks Eugene, that made it crystal clear. The variables share names, not scope.

Answer (score 2):

If `p` is a function parameter, `p = something` inside of the function body won't change the value at calling site. It doesn't matter if `p` is a pointer or not.

You're confusing it with `*p = something` and `p[foo] = something`.

Answer (score 1):

The pointer is passed by value, the change is localized to fun(). If you were to change *p that would be seen by main but not the change to the pointer itself.

Answer (score 1):

The variable "p" inside `fun()` is a local pointer on the stack.  You reassign p to point to q (also a local pointer) but when that function exists, the stack frames are popped and the value and the pointer go away.

If you want `fun()` to actually modify the value of the variable in the calling function, try changing the line:

```
p = &q;
```

to be:

```
*p = q;
```

This actually writes the value of `q` (10) to the address pointed to by `p`, rather than *re-assigning* `p` to point to something else.

Answer (score 1):

You give a copy of the pointer to the function as parameter. So the function cannot change the original.
You probably want to give a pointer to the pointer, which enables the function to alter the pointed-to pointer.

```
void fun(int **p) 
{ 
  static int q = 10; 
  *p = &q; 
}     

int main() 
{ 
  int r = 20; 
  int *p = &r; 
  fun(&p); 
  printf("%d", *p); 
  return 0; 
}
```

This however is quite risky, not to say insane.
In my example I changed the local variable to static, in order to avoid the most hideous consequences of returning a pointer to a local variable.
You probably have to redesign on quite a large scope to get a clean solution for whatever you are trying.

Comment: I wouldn't call it insane, the funny part is in the "discussion" section of the website I took this from, they passed a reference to a pointer to the `fun` function, and the fun function took a double pointer as a parameter. It was different than their original question.

Answer (score 0):

the p in the function gets the value of the p in main thus the address of r, then in the function you assign address of q to the p in the function. but the pointer p which is in main is not at all affected by the pointer p in fun thus pointer p in main still has address of variable r. Obviously now you know why it prints 20.

Answer (score 0):

Your expectation would hold true if your code inside the function was:

```
*p = q;
```

This would change the value inside the address pointed by p to the value held by variable q (which is local to the function).

Answer (score 0):

In C, values passed into a function are passed *by value*; that is, they are *copied* into the function. The `p` in `fun` is a copy of the `p` in `main`. This copy is changed, and then discarded as `fun` returns, leaving the `p` in `main` the same.

Incidentally, if it *had* worked as you expected, `printf` probably would not have printed `10`. The variable `q` in `fun` is local, and is destroyed as soon as `fun` exits. In practice this usually means it’s still in memory, but after the end of the stack*; the call to `printf` probably overwrites `q` with some of `printf`’s parameters or with other local data.

---

* Actually, since it’s never used except to take its address for `p`, which in turn is never used, in practice the compiler will optimize it out completely unless you use `-O0`.

Answer (score 0):

Outside the function fun ( inside main ), the variable 'q' is non existent and therefore its address is not present in p. When you dereference 'p' inside main function it has address of 'r' and not 'q'. If you dereference 'p' inside fun it will have address of 'q' and display 10.